# I can't for the life of me figure out how to customize color in ncmpcpp

Tags: customization, mpd, ncmpcpp

I finally was able to get ncmpcpp setup on my new eOS install (after giving up out of frustration on a previous install) and I love it. I really want to change to colors though and I know this is possible bc my endless googling has shown me numerous screenshots. I've read over the config file again and again and I see mention of color but can't seem to figure out where I can actually make the changes, and anything/everything I've tried has been fruitless. Would someone be able to show me the lines in the config file that can be edited to change color, and explain how to do that? Thank you in advance!